# Object and class analogy

Tags: oop

Recently I faced an interview. They asked me "If this room is a class ,then what is object here? ". I could not answer that time. When I came back home , I thought "if room is a class , object is interview room/kitchen room(instance of room)."

Am I right ?

Comment: You *could* say that if the blueprints of this room are the class, then the room is an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be pretty much the same, taking in mind the *Classes vs. Objects* explanation in [Code Complete, 2nd Edition](http://www.cc2e.com/Default.aspx)

> A key concept in object-oriented design is the differentiation
>   between objects and classes. An object is any specific entity that exists in your program
>   at run time. A class is the static thing you look at in the program listing. An
>   object is the dynamic thing with specific values and attributes you see when you run
>   the program. For example, you could declare a class Person that had attributes of
>   name, age, gender, and so on. At run time you would have the objects nancy, hank,
>   diane, tony, and so on—that is, specific instances of the class. If you’re familiar with
>   database terms, it’s the same as the distinction between “schema” and “instance.” You
>   could think of the class as the cookie cutter and the object as the cookie. This book
>   uses the terms informally and generally refers to classes and objects more or less interchangeably.

And I would just add to

> if room is a class , object is interview room/kitchen room(instance of room)

**at runtime**.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you are right. But in your post you say "*this room* is a class. In this situation, I think it's more like an object. Because it means *this* particular room.

In my view, class is a concept and object is an example of that object. We have the concept "room" and this room is a room, so it's an object of the Room class.